# How to group by with NULL value in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, null

In a `SELECT` statement, I somehow need to know if there is `NULL` in column `Coverage`; if so, then I want it to substitute with value that is NOT NULL and GROUP BY.

```
declare @TestTable table 
(
     ClaimNumber varchar(50), 
     Status varchar(50),
     Coverage varchar(50),
     Losses money
)

insert into @TestTable 
values ('WICCACA0000002', 'Open', 'Auto BIPD',5000),
       ('WICCACA0000003', 'Closed', 'Collision', 1000),
       ('WICCACA0000003', 'Closed', NULL, 2000)

select 
    ClaimNumber,
    Status,
    Coverage,
    SUM(Losses) as Losses 
from 
    @TestTable
group by 
    ClaimNumber, Status, Coverage
```

Result looks like this:

```
ClaimNumber     Status  Coverage    Losses
--------------------------------------------
WICCACA0000002  Open    Auto BIPD   5000.00
WICCACA0000003  Closed  NULL        2000.00
WICCACA0000003  Closed  Collision   1000.00
```

But I need the result look like this:

```
ClaimNumber     Status  Coverage    Losses
--------------------------------------------
WICCACA0000002  Open    Auto BIPD   5000.00
WICCACA0000003  Closed  Collision   3000.00
```

Comment: But if there are several rows with a different non-null values, which one to chose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `coalesce()` does what you want:

```
select ClaimNumber, Status, coalesce(Coverage, 'Collision') as coverage
       SUM(Losses) as Losses 
from @TestTable
group by ClaimNumber, Status, coalesce(Coverage, 'Collision');
```

Alternatively, if there is only one value in `Coverage` (as in your sample data), just use an aggregation function:

```
select ClaimNumber, Status, max(Coverage) as coverage
       SUM(Losses) as Losses 
from @TestTable
group by ClaimNumber, Status;
```

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about MAX() function